# find all headers file begin with vowels in /usr/include

Tags: command-line, find, regex

I need to find all headers from `/usr/include` that begin with vowels (a,e,i,o,u)

Example:

```
acpi.h 
aclinux.h
ah.h 
...
```

I don't know how to do it , I tried something with grep but I didn't make it up.

Comment: begin with a || e || i || o ||u and end with .h

Comment: OK, I've got to ask: what's the use case here?

Comment: @user3582615 - as explained previously - please add details to what copyright issues you are referring to.  If you dont want to say publicly, click the contact-us link below to state your case.  At the moment, we cannot allow you to deface your question by removing the information relevant to the question.

Comment: @user3582615,what are you exactly wanting?You are editing your question continuously and changing the question and the answers are becoming irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple way by using `ls` command:

```
ls /usr/include/[aeiou]*.h
```

also you can use `find` command with `-regex` option as following:

```bsh
find /usr/include -type f -regextype "posix-extended" -iregex '^\.\/(a|e|i|o|u).*\.h$'
```

```bsh
-regex pattern
    File  name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For
    example, to match a file named './fubar3', you can use the regular expression '\.\/fub.*'  or '.*b.*3' or '.*bar.',
    but not 'f.*r3'. The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expres‐
    sions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.

-iregex pattern
    Like -regex, but the match is case insensitive.

-regextype type
    Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the
    command line. Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic,
    posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

---

```
^\.\/[aeiou].*\.h$
```

[image: ^./[aeiou].*.h$]

#### Explanation:

- `^` is anchor for start of the filename(or better start the path of file)
- `\.\/` matches only `./` (a single dot followed by a slash)
- `(a|e|i|o|u)` is group of match. will match one of `a` or(`|`) `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` from beginning of filename after first `./`; or alternatively you can just use character-class `[aeiou]`.
- `.*` matches any character after vowels words
- `\.` matches single dot character, and
- `h$` matches character `h` in end of the filename(The `$` is anchor for end of filename)

Comment: How did you make that graph? Is there a tool for that purpose?

Comment: @don.joey have a look here http://www.regexper.com/

Answer (score 3):

The GNU version of `find` supports basic filename globs as part of the `-name` pattern, including the `[...]` character set construct. So it seems like you can just do

```
find /usr/include -name '[aeiou]*\.h'
```

or

```
find /usr/include -iname '[aeiou]*\.h'
```

if you want to match case-insensitively.

Answer (score 2):

This is also helpful.Use simple 'grep' with the help of regular expression..

```
ls /usr/include/ | grep '^[aeiou].*\.h$'
```

For the regular expressions given with 'grep'(i.e.,the meaning of `'^[aeiou].*\.h$'`) see the following link
[Regular Expression](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html)